# javascript Cookie with variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, cookies

I'm trying to store the OldURL into the cookie data - but everytime it puts the expires date and everything? The content of the cookie is expiration date and URL, and the real expiration date is delete on browser close?

```
document.cookie = "MyTracker="+oldURL+";expires=1 Jan 2050 23:59:59 UTC; path=/";
```

Comment: when I view the cookies content it is showed as like http://www.google.com/1Jan2050..etc

Comment: Every time you view the cookie content it gives a 404 error?

Comment: @peter HTTP404Only cookies :P

Comment: no...it's combining the expiration date and oldURL into the content of the cookie and setting the cookies expiration date to delete on browser exit.

Comment: So what is your problem, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Hmz, [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/vDm4E/) the definition you're using. I can safely say it's either the way you're testing the cookie or the value of oldURL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below:

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

and check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp